# How to show 10th to 20th child in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have a table with 100 entries for example.
Now, as soon as the user clicks on a button, all table-entries (tr-tag) should hide and only 20. to 29. tr should be shown.

How can I do that?

What I found out:
`$('table tbody tr').eq(20).show();`

This jQuery snippet finds me the 20th element of the table, but how can I tell jQuery, show 20-29?
I don't want to hardcode it.

Comment: `.eq` is 0-based. So saying `.eq(20)` gets the 21st element.

Comment: Flagged duplicate. In short, [`$('table tbody tr').slice(20, 30).show();`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) (give or take, you get the idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showRows(minVal, maxVal) {

    var i = minVal-1;
    var j = maxVal;

    for(i; i<j; i++) {
       $('table tbody tr').eq(i).show();
    }
}

showRows(20, 30); //show rows 20-29
```

Comment: thanks, i don't know why i didn't think of a loop :)